# Issue: Deployment in polygon mumbai

Tags: truffle, metamask, polygon

Deployment is not happening in Polygon Mumbai network using Metamask and Infura url.

Please see https://forum.matic.network/t/trying-to-deploy-in-mumbai-testnet-using-dedicated-rpc-url-failed/2810.

I am not getting proper response from the support team.

Here is my truffle config
[image]

I have multiple contracts to be deployed and eventually I get following error

```
“Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!”
```

My transaction never completes and is in pending mode.
[image]

It's not working even if I set `gasPrice` in my config.
Is there anyone who is familiar with such issue and guide me?

Comment: Please, include all the details in the question. That forum link may change or the forum shutdown and the question will become incomplete.